# did i must dispose BitmapFont generated by FreeTypeFontGenerator

Tags: java, memory-leaks, libgdx

in my project i use `FreeTypeFontGenerator` for generating fonts

when dispose i used to just call `FreeTypeFontGenerator.dispose()`

my question is

is enough to just dispose generator or must also dispose the `BitmapFont` Object

many thanks advance

Comment: BitmapFont should be disposed too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, indeed it is to be disposed. In fact, every instance of Classes that implement `Disposable`, must be. Check out this post: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Memory-management